# How to make my variable global and how to make the program wait until certain condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

Just started my coding stuff so it is still hard for me to understand some things. 
So I have created a script Nightmare that uses library for autotests, but I don't understand why my variable `value` is not global.

1) How can I export "`value`" from the "if condition" and show it in console?
Right now I am getting `1` as a result.

2) how can I postpone showing the `value` variable until the test is done? I think that `setTimeout function` is not good for this.

```
 const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
let value = '1';


nightmare
.goto('some-link-here')

.type('input#register-form-promo','111112')
.insert('input#register-form-username','Test')
.insert('input#register-form-email','kodjima33@gmail.com')
.insert('input#register-form-password','Password123456')
.evaluate(() => {
    var allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
        if (allButtons[i].innerText == 'Зарегистрироваться') allButtons[i].id = 'loginbutton';
    }
})
.click('button[id=loginbutton]')
.evaluate(function (value) {
    var element =  document.getElementsByClassName('help-block')[3];
    if (element.innerHTML == "Значение «Promo» неверно.") {
        value = true;
    console.log(value) }
        else {
        value = false;
        console.log(value)
        }
    }
  )
.wait(1000)
.end()
.then(result => {

}); 
setTimeout(function (){

    console.log(value);

  }, 10000);
```

Comment: instead of using setTimeout, you can put console.log(value) inside the then block, so basically then block will execute after all the process has been done

Answer (score 1):

The code you are have written is asynchronous. So if you write the `console.log(value)` inside the setTime out you are predicting that the above set of codes will complete in 10000 ms. This is a wrong approach because what happens if the operation takes more than 10000ms, you wont be able to see the updated value in your console.log. So you should add another `then()` after the `evaluate` function and

```
 const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
 const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
 let value = '1';
 nightmare
 .goto('some-link-here')
 .type('input#register-form-promo','111112')
 .insert('input#register-form-username','Test')
 .insert('input#register-form-email','kodjima33@gmail.com')
 .insert('input#register-form-password','Password123456')
 .evaluate(() => {
   var allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
   for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
    if (allButtons[i].innerText == 'Зарегистрироваться') allButtons[i].id = 'loginbutton';
   }
  })
  .click('button[id=loginbutton]')
  .evaluate(function (value) {
    var element =  document.getElementsByClassName('help-block')[3];
    if (element.innerHTML == "Значение «Promo» неверно.") {
      value = true;
     }
     else {
       value = false;
     }
     // a new function
     doSomething(value)
   })
  .wait(1000)
  .end()
  .then(result => {

  }); 

  function doSomething(value) {
    console.log(value)
  }
```

Comment: I just pasted your code and got this error

.end()
  ^

TypeError: nightmare.goto(...).type(...).insert(...).insert(...).insert(...).evaluate(...).click(...).evaluate(...).then(...).end is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/administrator/Documents/exp/Cryptofund/nightmare2.js:32:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:650:14)
...

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I think  .then()  can only be called at the end. What you can do is call a function inside the evaluate and it will console the value. I will update the answer